# PerspectiveCamera 3d graphics tutorials libgdx

Tags: android, android-emulator, libgdx

Does anyone know of any good tutorials for PrespectiveCamera which are not deprecated. Anything related to 3d graphics actually would be great..

Comment: You're sure orthographic is working? [There is one ctor with three parameters](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.html#OrthographicCamera%28float,%20float,%20float%29), and the actual parameters don't look correct to me. Also, show the code using the perspective one.

Comment: @Stefan Hanke Sorry, i forgot to change the name to PerspectiveCamera, OrthographicCamera works with just the first 2 parameters, not with the third. PerspectiveCamera requres 3 parameters.

Comment: OK, `fov=1` seems too limited, see [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectionViewportCamera). Note the default clip planes!

Comment: That tutorial is deprecated... i had a hard time making one of the other deprecated tutorials actually work since too many things have changed... is there one that is not deprecated that you know of?

Comment: 1. These tutorials don't seem deprecated. I've used the featured 0.9.4 release, and the code works like a charm (tested on a honeycomb device) 2. **Please stop re-defining your question**. [SO is no forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128550/182308).

Comment: Your comments have been so un-helpful. There is a REASON why it is under the "DEPRECATED" tab. I've actually talked to libgdx about this and they have told me NOT to follow the deprecated tutorials. The reason why i changed what i was looking for was because i realized that this would be more helpful, seeing as no one had an answer....

Comment: I'm sorry, this missed my eyes.

Comment: Its ok, i'm sorry for being harsh...just irritated that it's going no where..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/).